# Enter play eclipsify command display an error "No such file or directory"

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am new in PlayFramework. I created a small play project. Now I need to alter that project.

This is my folder structure `E:\java\project\code\ace`. I have all sub folders in to ace. Now I run the command "play eclipsify" it show an error like "No such files or directory".

I need to open my project in Eclipse environment.

I face this error in my command prompt:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\java\project\code\resources/eclipse/.project'

Comment: You need to run `play eclipsify` from _inside_ your project directory (`E:\java\project\code\ace`).

Answer (score 10):

Not sure about playframework 1, but in playframework 2 I type `play eclipse` (not `eclipsify` as the [play web](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/IDE) says) inside the project directory. Also `javac` needs to be on the path

Answer (score 5):

I am using play 2.3.6 which includes the Activator 1.2.10.
With this distribution the 'play' command has been replaced by 'activator'.

So the command you need is:

```
activator eclipse
```

And ensure you run this from inside your play application directory.

Some of the documentation was written before this change and is out of date, but there was an announcement here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/bTvJbeR_zvU/J3reqk6Xo4AJ

Comment: From your project/play directory. Don't forget activator needs to be on your path!

Answer (score 0):

1.Open command line.

2.Go to your project folder in your work space.Using this command cd Workspace/your project folder.
3. Run Command **play eclipse**.

4.Then run Command **play run**.